# Second touch after UILongPressGestureRecognizer has began

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and when I use one finger it works properly. When I lay down a second finger this is not captured by the recognizer, the `delegate` keeps being called but only with the first touch, `[recognizer numberOfTouches]` is always 1.

If I set `[recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2]` it also works properly, I get `[recognizer numberOfTouches]` = 2 when I lay 2 fingers down simultaneouly.

My conclusion is: after a `UILongPressGesture` is recognized and began, a second touch won't change it. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes that's the expected behaviour. The control will be limited by the amount of touches you specified before launch.

Answer (score 0):

You could add two different UILongPressGestureRecognizers, one set up with `numberOfTouchesRequired` = 1, and one = 2.
You also probably want the one that only expects for 1 finger to fail if it recognizes the other one (in case the user taps with one finger, and inmediately after puts down another finger).

It would be something like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *oneFingerLongPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerLongPressed:)];
oneFingerLongPressGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *twoFingersLongPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingersLongPressed:)];
twoFingersLongPressGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;

[oneFingerLongPressGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:twoFingersLongPressGesture];

UIView *someView;

[someView addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerLongPressGesture];
[someView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingersLongPressGesture];

[oneFingerLongPressGesture release];
[twoFingersLongPressGesture release];
```